# CAKEPHP Delete & View In the controller

Tags: cakephp, view

http://pastebin.com/TPDcNaAp

Cleaner to pastebin. 
http://webdesign4.georgianc.on.ca/~100141468/comp2084/todo/Employees

I am trying to work with cake to be able to add/delete/edit and view without using scaffold. I  cannot seem to get delete and view to work correctly. That is my code in the pastebin, anyone see what I am doing wrong? The file is EmployeesController.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your view you haven't create the file:

```
Error: Confirm you have created the file: /home/100141468/public_html/comp2084/todo/app/View/Employees/view.ctp
```

Change your view code to look like:

```
$this->set('employee', $this->Employee->read(null, $id));
```

Your view will look like whatever you want, use whatever html markup you need to display the data, whether it be a table, divs, a list, etc. In your view you will have the `$employee` variable available, do a `debug($employee);` to see its contents.

Ex: `<div><b>Name:</b> <?php echo $employee['Employee']['name']; ?></div>`

You may also want to check if the record exists first to redirect back to the previous page and let the user know that record does not exists (set a flash message).

For your delete, you are accessing it by GET but not allowing it in your code:

```
 if ($this->request->is('get')) {
    throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
 }
```

If you want to delete by accessing the url `/employees/delete/{id}` remove that block of code.

Comment: I am unsure what you are saying for the delete... Can you show me how the code would look.

Comment: lol never mind, thank you :) Just figured out what you meant!

Comment: One more question, if the view looks correct in the controller, what would the code be for the view.ctp?

Comment: Thanks man, you've just made everything work 100%. Less stress for me too.